# Typo on https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, spelling, documentation

In https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts

> Most applications should use the question or answer specific methods, but /posts is available for those rare cases where any activity is of intereset.

'intereset' should be 'interest':

> Most applications should use the question or answer specific methods, but /posts is available for those rare cases where any activity is of **interest**.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate:  [Typos in API documentation](https://stackapps.com/q/8044/34061)

Comment: Some more [Typos in API documentation](https://stackapps.com/q/6899/37357)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We pushed a fix for this typo in the latest build. Thanks for the report.